# Importing module from package

Tags: python

I am trying to import a module from a package set up as per instructions from [Modules Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html). My directory tree is:

```
$ pwd
/home/me/lib/python/pygplib

$ ls *
__init__.py

atcf:
atcf.py  __init__.py
```

I am able to import `pygplib` but `pygplib.atcf` does not seem to exist:

```
In [1]: import pygplib

In [2]: dir(pygplib)
Out[2]: ['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']
```

What am I doing wrong? All my `__init__.py` files are blank. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `import pygplib.atcf.atcf` to get what's in that file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`atcf` is not imported automatically into the `pygplib` namespace, but you can arrange for this to happen by putting

```
import atcf
```

in `pygplib/__init__.py`.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I need, as I would like to have submodules available in the namespace on package import.

Comment: Also note that if you want the stuff in atcf.py to be in the `pygplib.atcf` namespace, you'll want to put `from atcf import *` in `pyglib/atcf/__init__.py`.

Answer (score 3):

Submodules don't get imported when you import the top package, and thus don't appear in `dir`. Instead, do

```
from pygplib import atcf
```

Or

```
from pygplib.atcf import atcf
```